# Visual Studio 2013 one-click publish

Tags: visual-studio-2013, publish

I have a project I've been working on in C# that I want to publish, but the one-click publish option produces a setup.exe which seems to run fine but then only generates a 1kB click-once application reference. So what on earth do I have to do to generate a proper setup file?

Comment: If VS2013 is anything like VS2010, then you'll need at least the Professional version to create a 'proper' installer.

Answer (score 0):

The binaries should be small if the application is small. Most of the heavy implementation is provided by the .net framework.

If you target a framework that you suspect won't be present on your audience's versions of Windows you can include the .net framework redistributable packages and other dependencies through:

1 - Right Click the project in Solution Explorer
2 - On the properties tab that will show up, select the Publish tab (should be one of the last ones)
3 - On publish settings click on Prerequisites... 
4 - Select the desirable prerequisites and change the radio button to "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application"

---

If you don't like ClickOnce you can use InstallShield Limited Edition project. It will create a more customizable setup experience and the free version is a good start.

Add a project to the solution under Templates -> Other Project Types -> Setup and Deployment -> Enable InstallShield Limited Edition

It will guide to the InstallShield page to register and download the free version of the plugin.

Comment: The oneclick already has .NET 4.5 checked (if I try to run the generated executable on a clean computer it tells me that's the one missing). As for the InstallShield project I downloaded/installed it and visual studio is telling me it couldn't find it.

Edit: ran a Repair and restarted VS, I'll get back to you when I get through the stps

Comment: Ok definitely not working. First of all I don't need something more customizable I need something that just works doesn't matter how basic. Secondly the installshield method doesn't actually have a way to publish it, it can throw back my own files onto my C: drive, and tell me other users might not have the required framework well that isn't helpful at all

Comment: Hi user220329, on the clickonce scenario, have you changed the radio button to "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application"? This should make clickonce include the framework with the application.

Comment: Also with InstallShield you can add custom actions that trigger framework installation during the setup process. You can even include the framework with the package. Perhaps you should take a look at InstallShield documantation, as there is a learning curve for InstallShield.

Comment: What radio button are you referring to?

Comment: The radio button in the same window you select prerequisites. There are three, you should select the one in the middle.